# iCloud TextEdit folder not visible on icloud.com service (stuck in uploading state)

Tags: icloud

I have enabled on my Mac the iCloud Drive and its TextEdit folder where I uploaded one specific file, but if I login to icloud.com icloud drive I don't see this folder there. Why?

**my macbook folder:**
[image: my pc]

**no textedit folder on icloud webservice:**
[image: web service without the folder]

**EDIT:
it is stuck in uploading state... which is really not pleasant, because otherwise eg the Notes synchronization works great.. and i know this also from the developer view that it worked right away, so why the icloud drive (textedit etc folders) is that shitty service that it cannot work that good too? moreover when just yesterday i ordered the bigger space of icloud (50GB for some month fee).**

[image]

Comment: So every other folder is in iCloud Drive?  What about everything else you have in iCloud, is that all sycned properly?

Comment: @fsb hi it is stuck in uploading state i noticed... check my edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a wild stab at the dark here and tell you to create a folder within icloud.com named whatever >> then, go to your mac and symlink your TextEdit folder to Whatever folder you've created within the online service.

Comment: hi, i also tried to upload one text file directly at icloud.com as you say, and yes it is uploaded there, and available on all devices, but i think there is a difference with this textedit folder.. that it seems you can use the file in this folder like on your pc, but if you upload just soem file you can only read it i guess.